# fetching multiple cookies based on start of name

Tags: javascript, cookies, match

I'm trying to call a bunch of cookies I have stored back onto a page. There are multiple ones with names like todo-0, todo-1 (you get the idea). So, I'm trying to figure out a way of calling all cookies that's name starts with 'todo-' and then print the value of that cookie to my page inside a table.

I was kinda hoping it would be as simple as:

```
if (document.cookie.name.match(/^todo-/)) {
    todoTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', document.cooke.value);
}
```

But I get an error saying `no method 'match'`.

Any ideas about the best way to root through multiple cookies and fetch ones the start with todo- ?

Comment: there is no such thing like `document.cookie.name`, `document.cookie` contains string with all cookies assigned to document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
var myCookies = document.cookie.split(";");

for(var i = 0; i < myCookies.length; i++)
{
    var cookie = myCookies[i].trim().split("=");

    if(cookie[0].indexOf("todo-") === 0) {
        todoTable.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', decodeURIComponent(cookie[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: you should decode value first as it is url encoded `decodeURIComponent(cookie[1])` (same thing with cookie names, but in `todo-` there is nothing to decode so that step can be omitted in this case)

Comment: and `String.trim` is supported only by modern browsers - just a notice ;)

Comment: This is great guys! It didn't seem to work at first, but adding an alert in the if statement shows that each one is being picked up correctly. 

However the content isn't being placed into the table at all, kinda weird.

Seems to be the `decodeURIComponent(cookie[1])` part, it I just have it say `cookie` it shows up. Is this expected?

Comment: Just noticed a potential issue with this approach however. Inside the cookie is some HTMl with `=` in it! Ofc this code gets rid of all those `=` so the code doesn't display correctly :/ 

Also, it displays the name of the cookie, is there a way to just call the value?

Comment: Never mind! I wasn't encodingURI in the first place. All sorted, amazing guy, thank you!